# HTML CSS and Visual Studio Professional - 2015 (Not to be confused with Visual Studio Code)

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio

I use VS 2015 for all typescript and nodejs development. It has amazing templates for typescript and excellent debugging capabilities.

For HTML and CSS, I need to keep pressing F5 to see the result preview. Is there a live HTML preview (like in a split screen?).

Answer (score 1):

You can enable browser link so that as you edit the html/css, the browser will update. See pic below:

[image]